# Trying to scrape a website, and I cannot return the Javascript. I've tried selenium, geckodriver, requests

Tags: python, web-scraping

I believe the tag I'm after is class="row row-stripped py-1 ml-0". And I'll need to get the data within the tags.

```
import asyncio
from requests_html import HTMLSession
if asyncio.get_event_loop().is_running(): # Only patch if needed (i.e. running in Notebook, Spyder, etc)
    import nest_asyncio
    nest_asyncio.apply()

session = HTMLSession()
url='https://www.canlii.org/en/on/onltb/nav/date/2021/'
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()

url = 'https://www.canlii.org/en/on/onltb/nav/date/2021/'.format(id=bibtex_id)
x=[]
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get(url)

    response = session.get(xhr_url, params={'id': bibtex_id})
    x.append(response.content)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's a json object not that hard to find

```
import requests
url='https://www.canlii.org/en/on/onltb/nav/date/2021/'
r = requests.get(url+'items')
print(r.json())
```